# Set up nginx to allow cross-domain request for subdomain

Tags: nginx, cross-domain

I've got two domains:

domain.com
sub.domain.com

domain.com needs to make an ajax request to sub.domain.com. I realize that the browser will block this if the request is hardcoded to be sub.domain.com. I tried the following nginx conf:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;

    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/api/$1; }
```

However, I still get the following error in the browser (Chrome):

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

How can I set up nginx to instruct the browser to allow cross domain requests between domain.com and sub.domain.com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you need to create this inside the location or server block

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin sub.example.com; # < this is the needed header
    # rest of the configuration
}
```

Comment: should this work if I am testing on localhost? my domain on localhost is like example:8080

Comment: Yes, it should work just fine, you could also just set it to allow "*" and not worry about domain names

Comment: its not working nor with domain not with * :( maybe this somehow does not reach this setting but I cannot think of how to check

Comment: Check the response headers in the browser dev tools, both chrome and ff have that by default (usually by f12, check network tab)

Comment: thanks, - I see the line "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" and then in another line is "Location: https:// ..." So it is redirected. And not I will try to move on from there :)

Comment: You should probably update your code, make it send the request to the new url (one in the location header) and do the same, check the returned headers and if it contains the allow access header